# how can you have grep start searching from specified line number

Tags: bash

If I need to start grepping a file from line num 1293 all the way to the end of the file how can I do that?

**More detailed info in case it helps:**
I am trying to whip a quick function in my bashrc that lets me quickly search vim snippet files for a particular snippet echoing the snippet name and associated command(s) to screen. So I have no probs getting the line num for the snippet name and even printing out the command on the following line num. But if the snippet is a multi-line command then I need to grep for the next line beginning with snippet "^snippet " and then return all lines between, but I cannot find any details how I can go about getting grep to start its search starting from a particular line num.

A secondary question is how in a .bashrc function can I exit the function early? When I use the 'exit' command
 currently commented out in the funct below the terminal itself exits/closes rather than just exiting the funct.

```
function vsls() {
if [[ "$2" =~ ^(html|sh|vim)$ ]] ; then 
    sPath="$2".snippets
elif [[ "$2" =~ ^(html|sh|vim).snippets$ ]] ; then 
    sPath="$2"
else
    echo "\nExiting. You did not enter a recognized vim snippets file name."
#   exit 69
fi      
    lnN=$(more $HOME/.vim/snippets/"$sPath"|grep -nm 1 $1|sed -r 's/^([0-9]*):.*$/\1/') ; echo "\$lnN: ${lnN}"
    cntr="$lnN"
    sed -n "$cntr"p "$HOME/.vim/snippets/$sPath"
    ((cntr++))
    sed -n "$cntr"p "$HOME/.vim/snippets/$sPath"
}
```

@chepner
I don't know why (lack of know-how likely) but without specifying 'more' I get a permissions error:

```
03:43 ~ $ fLNum=$($HOME/.vim/snippets/"$sPath"|grep -nm 1 tdotti|sed -r 's/^([0-9]*):.*$/\1/') ; echo "\$fLNum: ${fLNum}"
bash: /home/user/.vim/snippets/html.snippets: Permission denied
$fLNum: 
03:43 ~ $ fLNum=$(more $HOME/.vim/snippets/"$sPath"|grep -nm 1 tdotti|sed -r 's/^([0-9]*):.*$/\1/') ; echo "\$fLNum: ${fLNum}"
$fLNum: 1293
```

**Now working as desired**:
I stuck with sed since I feel most comfortable using sed. I have used the -n print opt before, but not too often so it totally escaped my mind to try something like that.

```
function vsls() {
if [[ "$2" =~ ^(html|sh|vim)$ ]] ; then 
    sPath="$2".snippets
elif [[ "$2" =~ ^(html|sh|vim).snippets$ ]] ; then 
    sPath="$2"
else
    echo "\nExiting. You did not enter a recognized vim snippets file name."
#   exit 69
fi      

    fLNum=$(more $HOME/.vim/snippets/"$sPath"|grep -nm 1 "snippet $1"|sed -r 's/^([0-9]*):.*$/\1/') ; echo "\$fLNum: ${fLNum}"  #get line number of the snippet name searched, entered as input $1
    ((tLNum1 = fLNum+=1)) ; echo "\$tLNum1: ${tLNum1}"  # tmpLineNum is next line num from which to start next grep search for lineNum of next snippet entry to determine where commands of desired snippet end
    tLNum2=$(sed -n "${tLNum1},$ p" $HOME/.vim/snippets/"$sPath"|grep -nm 1 "snippet"|sed -r 's/^([0-9]*):.*$/\1/') ; echo "\$tLNum2: ${tLNum2}"    #lineNum of next 'snippet entry'
    let sLNum=tLNum2+fLNum sLNum-=1 ; let sLNum-=1 ; echo "\$sLNum: ${sLNum}"   #tmpLineNum2 is not actual line num in file, but rather the number of lines since the start of the second search, that is necessarily somewhere within the file: so if second search begins on line 1294, for all intents and purpose actual line num 1294 is line 1 of the new (second) search; therefore I need to add the tLNum2 with fLNum to determine actual lineNum in the of the next snippet entry 

    echo ""
    sed -n "${fLNum},${sLNum} p" "$HOME/.vim/snippets/$sPath"
    echo ""
}
```

But it is curious why I needed to do:

```
let sLNum=tLNum2+fLNum sLNum-=1 ; let sLNum-=1
```

to get the correct line number of the second grep search. I only got lucky fooling around, b/c I would have thought:

```
let sLNum=tLNum2+fLNum sLNum-=1
```

or:
let sLNum=tLNum2+fLNum ; let sLNum-=1
should have done the trick; that is, secondLineNum = tmpLNum2 + firstLineNum and then secondLineNum - 1. But the result would never end up 1 less but always equal to tLNum+fLNum. It would be good to learn why that did not work as expected.

But its working. so thanks.

Comment: `more` is meant for interactive use. Just pass the file name as the 2nd required argument to `grep`.

Comment: You need more because you're trying to execute the file. Use `cat` or `grep -opts patt file`

Comment: @glennjackman: yeap cat did work just the same. Not being interactive like more as chepner pointed out is surely the better solution. It did occur to me to +x the file but then I could not for the life of me think why it would need exe permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or with sed like this:

```
sed -n "1293,$ p" yourfile | grep xyz
```

Or, if the line number is in a variable called `line`:

```
sed -n "${line},$ p" yourfile | grep xyz
```

Or, if you want your `grep` to find nothing in the first 1292 lines, but still report the correct line number if you are using `grep -n`, you can just get the (empty) hold buffer for grep to look at for lines 1 to 1292

```
sed "1,1292g" yourfile | grep -n xyz
```

Comment: Goodness, don't need grep if you use sed: `sed -n '1293,$ {/xyz/ p}' file`

Comment: @glenn jackman good point, but I need the -m 1 feature grep offers to return only the first matched line num. I am pretty sure sed has a similar feature but I don't know the syntax off the top of my head and so I preferred to go with what was handy.

Comment: I missed that point (didnt' read the giant question). To bail out after the first match: `sed -n '1293,$ {/xyz/ {p; q}}' file`

Comment: @glennjackman : Yes, very elegant solution - I have lots to learn.

Comment: I only use sed for very simple scripts. I really hate the 1 letter commands. Anything complicated, I'll go to awk next.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is better suited for this

```
awk '/search_pattern/ && NR > 1292' filename
```

Comment: I think you need `&&` between the two conditions. And in this particular case, the `{print $0}` is not necessary, since that's the default action. `awk '/search_pattern/ && NR > 1292' filename` should do it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -n +1293 file | grep ....
```